# How to get updated values for session attribute from database?

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-listeners

I'm working on Web application where Employee Details(attributes such as name,id,skills) are displayed in registered.jsp once employee is validated.This is basically making DAO call to database & setting Employee object as session attribute..But I'm giving flexibility to user to update their details by redirecting it to other JSP(update.jsp) ..Once details updated, i want to show updated session attribute details without hitting DB again..I heard HttpSessionBindingListener can be implemented to sync attribute object from database..How to do that?Can someone guide me